# Calculate average value for 5 mins inPerl

Tags: perl, datetime, average

I have a data set with three different fields (`Date`, `Time`, `Value`)as follows:

```
2014-01-24 23:32:01.874 45
2014-01-24 23:32:02.198 71
2014-01-24 23:32:02.302 94
2014-01-24 23:32:02.439 48
2014-01-24 23:32:02.574 82
2014-01-24 23:32:02.724 51
2014-01-24 23:32:02.913 15
2014-01-24 23:32:02.964 77
2014-01-24 23:32:02.989 49
2014-01-24 23:32:03.017 42
2014-01-24 23:32:03.025 1
2014-01-24 23:32:03.085 67
2014-01-24 23:32:03.136 53
2014-01-24 23:32:03.200 46
2014-01-24 23:32:03.240 72
2014-01-24 23:32:03.257 0
2014-01-24 23:32:03.296 36
```

How do I write a Perl script to calculate average of the Value Field for every 5 mins ?

Desired output:

```
Time  Average Value
23:30 20
23:35 35
23:40 15
```

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Solve almost any datetime need with Time::Piece](http://perltricks.com/article/59/2014/1/10/Solve-almost-any-datetime-need-with-Time-Piece)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can normalise the timestamps to five minute periods by converting to a number of seconds, dividing by 300, taking the integer and multiplying what you get by 300.

Taking that approach (and using Perl's standard Time::Piece module to do the parsing and formatting) gives something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';

my %data;
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my ($date, $time, undef, $count) = split /[ \.]/;

  my $dt = Time::Piece->strptime("$date $time", $fmt);
  push @{$data{five_min($dt->epoch)}}, $count;
}

foreach my $period (sort keys %data) {
  my $total;
  $total += $_ for @{$data{$period}};
  my $avg = sprintf '%.2f', $total / @{$data{$period}};
  say localtime($period)->strftime($fmt), ' ', $avg;
}

sub five_min {
  my $epoch = shift;
  my $secs  = 5 * 60;
  return $secs * int($epoch / $secs);
}

__DATA__
2014-01-24 23:12:01.874 45
2014-01-24 23:12:02.198 71
2014-01-24 23:22:02.302 94
2014-01-24 23:22:02.439 48
2014-01-24 23:22:02.574 82
2014-01-24 23:32:02.724 51
2014-01-24 23:32:02.913 15
2014-01-24 23:32:02.964 77
2014-01-24 23:42:02.989 49
2014-01-24 23:42:03.017 42
2014-01-24 23:42:03.025 1
2014-01-24 23:52:03.085 67
2014-01-24 23:52:03.136 53
2014-01-24 23:52:03.200 46
2014-01-24 23:52:03.240 72
2014-01-24 23:52:03.257 0
2014-01-24 23:52:03.296 36
```

The output is:

```
$ ./avgtime 
2014-01-24 23:10:00 58.00
2014-01-24 23:20:00 74.67
2014-01-24 23:30:00 47.67
2014-01-24 23:40:00 30.67
2014-01-24 23:50:00 45.67
```

Answer (score 4):

Write Perl code to read the data line by line.

Maintain a counter variable that counts off the time in 5 minute increments, and an array that holds the lines of data that you are reading.

When the time of a data line exceeds the current counter variable value, calculate the average using the data in the array, increment the counter, and clear the array.  Add the new line to the cleared array, and contine the process.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the data to have 5 min intervalls:

```
2014-01-24 23:12:01.874 45
2014-01-24 23:12:02.198 71
2014-01-24 23:22:02.302 94
2014-01-24 23:22:02.439 48
2014-01-24 23:22:02.574 82
2014-01-24 23:32:02.724 51
2014-01-24 23:32:02.913 15
2014-01-24 23:32:02.964 77
2014-01-24 23:42:02.989 49
2014-01-24 23:42:03.017 42
2014-01-24 23:42:03.025 1
2014-01-24 23:52:03.085 67
2014-01-24 23:52:03.136 53
2014-01-24 23:52:03.200 46
2014-01-24 23:52:03.240 72
2014-01-24 23:52:03.257 0
2014-01-24 23:52:03.296 36
```

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n

BEGIN { use Date::Parse; }

push @r, [ $&, str2time($1).'.'.$2, $3 ] if /(.*?)\.(\d+) (\d+)\s*$/;

END {

  $ref = undef;
  $avg = 0.0;
  $cnt = 0;
  for(sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1]} @r) {
      unless ($ref) {
        $sum = $_->[2];
        $cnt = 1;
        $ref = $_->[1];
      } else {
        if ($_->[1] - $ref > 60.0*5) {
          printf "avg: %5.2f\n", $sum/$cnt;
          $ref = $_->[1];
          $sum = $_->[2];
          $cnt = 1;
        } else {
          $sum += $_->[2];
          $cnt++;
        }
      }
      printf "%s", $_->[0];
  }
  printf "avg: %5.2f\n", $sum/$cnt;
}
```

The output:

```
2014-01-24 23:12:01.874 45
2014-01-24 23:12:02.198 71
avg: 58.00
2014-01-24 23:22:02.302 94
2014-01-24 23:22:02.439 48
2014-01-24 23:22:02.574 82
avg: 74.67
2014-01-24 23:32:02.724 51
2014-01-24 23:32:02.913 15
2014-01-24 23:32:02.964 77
avg: 47.67
2014-01-24 23:42:02.989 49
2014-01-24 23:42:03.017 42
2014-01-24 23:42:03.025 1
avg: 30.67
2014-01-24 23:52:03.085 67
2014-01-24 23:52:03.136 53
2014-01-24 23:52:03.200 46
2014-01-24 23:52:03.240 72
2014-01-24 23:52:03.257 0
2014-01-24 23:52:03.296 36
avg: 45.67
```